# angularjs - $modalInstance.dismiss action redirects page to modal's templateUrl

Tags: angularjs

When `$modalInstance.dismiss` is initiated, the whole page is redirected to the modal's `templateUrl` instead of the modal is simply only closed. This does not happen when ESC is pressed or you press outside of the modal. Why could this be happening?

[Example behaviour](http://plnkr.co/edit/6pcLH4nMLnIN3R8p4Htd?p=preview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem appeared to be because the **Cancel** button was within a `<form>` tag. When a `<button>` is within a `<form>`, angularjs redirects the user to the `<form>`'s action url. Since with angularjs forms are not needed, removing the form tags resolved the problem. Another way would be to place the buttons outside the form's tag.

Comment: Sometimes the form tags are required (form validation). And sometimes it's not easy to move the button outside the form. In my case the top level form had a function registered with ng-submit. To prevent the function from being invoked I stopped click propagation from the cancel button's ng-click.